# Pebbles and paver installation for side walk

Tags: pavers, backyard, sidewalk

I am trying to improve my side-walk which basically goes to my backyard. Its roughly 30ft length by 4ft width. I want to install pebbles and pavers in the middle to make it look clean. I have no drainage issues or any other issues in the area. I live in Seattle where it rains a lot.

I`m looking for suggestion on which pebbles to use? Also I want to do it on my own so any tips on installation would be great. Also, would I need to put any polyethylene sheet before putting pebbles.

Thanks for any advice. I have attached pictures for reference to the space I want to install these.

[image: narrow area between house and fence]

[image: closer angle of the ground]

Comment: The pea-sized gravel in the photo seems a good candidate with the cover of one to two inches of sand. No sheeting is required.

Comment: The company from which you purchase the pavers should be able to give you suggestions for substrate. Most of us won't know what's available and cost-effective in your local area. It's usually a coarse sand or fine gravel.

Comment: @FreeMan, this will be a paved area on which one walks. I'm not sure what your point was there. I have the same thing around the side of my garage and I call it a sidewalk.